# scrollLeft works but scrollTop doesn't work

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have the following HTML with CSS `.container { overflow: scroll; }` etc.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div id="markers"></div>
  <img id="map" src="/img/map.jpg"/>
</div>
</body>
```

`map.jpg` is very large and I want to scroll to a fixed position like this:

```
$(function(){
  console.log($('.container').scrollTop());
  $('.container').scrollTop(1000);
  console.log($('.container').scrollTop());
  console.log($('.container').scrollLeft());
  $('.container').scrollLeft(1750);
  console.log($('.container').scrollLeft());
});
```

`scrollLeft` works fine but `scrollTop` doesn't. Below is the console output.

```
0
0
0
1750
```

I've been searching for half an hour but still don't know how to fix it...

---

**UPDATE:** CSS about `.container` `#markers` and `#map`

```
.container { overflow: scroll; width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 100%; max-height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { width: 5000px; max-width: 5000px; height: 2907px; max-height: 2907px; cursor: crosshair; }
#markers { position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you show us more CSS code about .container, #markers and #map ?

Comment: It's strange, perhaps try overflow: auto on .container instead of scroll.

Comment: @Sybio I managed to fix it by adding position: absolute; to .container

Comment: i have make an example on below fiddle link you can see their what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few trials, I managed to fix it by adding `position: absolute;` to `.container`

Answer (score 0):

check this code for and also u can check here for a live example http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/2uvRe/

this is html code

```
<div class="demo">
    <h1>lalala</h1>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>​
```

this is css code

```
div.demo {
background:#CCCCCC none repeat scroll 0 0;
border:3px solid #666666;
margin:5px;
padding:5px;
position:relative;
width:200px;
height:100px;
overflow:auto;
}
p { margin:10px;padding:5px;border:2px solid #666;width:1000px;height:1000px; }​
```

this is javascript code

```
$("div.demo").scrollTop(300);
    $("div.demo").scrollLeft(300);​
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a container with `overflow: auto` and the same problem: `.scrollLeft` worked fine, but `.scrollTop` didn't do anything.

After some experimentation, I could not figure out what caused this issue in my non-trivial CSS code, but I found out that switching to `scrollTo()` made my code work without any further changes.